# What can I do if Liskov Substitution Principle is violated?

Tags: java, c#, c++, oop, liskov-substitution-principle

Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) states that if an object o1 is a type of S and it can be substituted for object o2 that is a type of T without violating the original behavior(s) of all its users, then S is a subtype of T.

The common example used to show LSP violation is Rectangle and its derivative type, Square. The argument is that although intuitively the Square seems to be subtype of Rectangle, but there is some behavior of Square which is different from Rectangle. The conclusion is that the Square cannot be a subtype of Rectangle by LSP.

All explanations I discovered end there and I find it not helpful. I want to know what should I do if I have that problem? Create S which is not a subtype of T, and then what? What solutions do I have to solve it?

Can someone please enlighten me with an answer for the overhanging question?

**edit:** Rather than elaborating the example here, I refer you to this [article](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf).

Comment: `there is some behavior of Square which is different from Rectangle` Examples?

Comment: Are these differences relevant in your case? If not, you may still be able to derive square from rectangle.

Comment: @deviantfan : `mySquare.Length = 5;` also sets width to 5 whereas `myRectangle.Length = 5;` does not width to 5

Comment: @Jonny And why does something in your program (outside of Rectangle/Square) depends on that? (if it does, else there is no problem)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **'HAS A'** or **'USES'** relationship if you can not establish **'IS A'** relationship.

This means that instead of having class B inherit from class A, you can have class B contain an instance of class A. This is also good coding practice to avoid tight coupling between class A and class B.

Answer (score 1):

This question is reviewed in the book Effective C++ 3rd Edition by Scott Meyers, Addison Wesley May 2005. In chapter 6, Item 32.

There Meyers makes sample class for Rectangle and class for Square which inherits the first one and talks extensively about the arising problems using assertions.

The conclusion of the Item is:

"Public inheritance means “is-a.” Everything that applies to base
classes must also apply to derived classes, because every derived
class object is a base class object."

Currently the book can be found or bought on the internet.

Comment: good catch with the book reference

Answer (score 0):

The LSP is a more precise definition of the "is-a" relation, if you class violates the LSP is not a suitable candidate to be derived from the base class. It is a signal that something is wrong in your design.

Two point worth to be noticed: violating LSP is going to break the base class and not the derived class, this is very dangerous in legacy code with very little tests coverage, something that has a clear "is-a" relationship in the mathematical world (like square and rectangle) they may don't share that relationship in the domain of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the common properties into an interface or an abstract type and use this as base. Differences can still be implemented in the derived type.

This way you keep your IS-relation.

Answer (score 0):

The lesson to be learned from LSP and the rectange/square example is that **IS_A** has nothing to do with maths or biology or anything that seems obviously **IS_A** by intuition.

**IS_A** is solely a relationship of behavior. Square is not a rectangle in OOP, because it doesn't have the same behavior. But rectangle has the same behavior as square plus some extra which does not violate any behavior of square. So in OOP rectangle **IS_A** square and it makes perfect sense to implement it like that even if it defies maths and intuition.